# Descent of projective bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, moduli-spaces, geometric-invariant-theory, quotient-space

A problem studied in GIT is the descending of vector bundles (or more in general coherent sheaves) to quotients.
It is a result of Kempf that whenever we have a vector bundle over a quasiprojective scheme defined over $\mathbb{C}$ (or any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero)
$$\pi:E\to X$$
and a reductive group $G$ acting linearly on $E$ and $X$ with the property that
$$\pi(g\cdot v)=g\cdot \pi(v)$$
Let $X//G$ be the GIT quotient, then $E$ descends to a vector bundle
$$\bar{E}\to X//G$$
if for any $x\in X^{ss}$ (closed point) $Stab(x)$ acts trivially on $E_x$.
My problem is the following: i am interested to know if there is a similar condition which ensures that a projective bundle descends to the quotient.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can get a condition by combining the result cited in the question with the observation that projective $G$-bundle on $X$ is the same as a $\widetilde{G}$-bundle on $X$, where $\widetilde{G}$ is a central extension of $G$ by $\mathbf{G}_m$.